# Download video from Youtube

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm going to download video from Youtube using `PSYouTubeExtractor`. Every thing is fine but the saved file does not contain any video. It has 283 byte size only. I don't know what thing I'm going to wrong. Please help I'm new to objective C. Any kind of response will be appreciated.

this is code that I've used for downloading

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"YouTube", nil);

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  HELVETICA_NEUE_LIGHT_24,
  NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

self.youtubeUrl_Label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter YouTube URL:", nil);
self.youtubeUrl_Label.font = HELVETICA_NEUE_LIGHT_15;

self.go_button.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"GO", nil);
self.go_button.titleLabel.font = HELVETICA_NEUE_LIGHT_15;


extractor = [[PSYouTubeExtractor alloc] init]; }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
-(IBAction)go_button:(id)sender {

NSString* textFieldString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.textField.text];

NSURL *youTubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:textFieldString];

[extractor getVideoUrlForUrl:youTubeURL notificatoinName:@"URLDidFinishExtractingFromYouTubeURL"];

//NSURLConnection will download the video
con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:youTubeURL] delegate:self];}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
videoData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];}
```

////////////////////////////////////

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[videoData appendData:data]; }
```

////////////////

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

NSString* mediaPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Media"];

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:mediaPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:mediaPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.mp4",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

NSString* finalPath = [mediaPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

[videoData writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"LOCAL VIDEO LINK %@",filePath);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController) Is the new version of PSYouTubeExtractor. PSYouTubeExtractor was discontinued 2 years ago. It is possible that the Youtube API changed, thus making the PSYouTubeExtractor useless.

If you really want to debug the problem, check out what the NSURLResponse is in:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

And print the data you get (in NSString UTF8)